# Magento white page at backend and frontend after upgrade to new version

Tags: magento2

After Ugrade my website, both the backend and frontend of the site went blank. I have already searched the internet and tried out some possible solutions, but none of them works.

I seriously have no idea how I can solve this, so that’s why I’m here. I hope someone can help me. If you need more information, please ask, I don’t really know what’s necessary to answer my question.

Email: bestlinkt@gmail.com

Comment: Check you email

Comment: Have you check magento log files?

Comment: Yes, I've try my possible power to resolve the issue